# Extreme Low FPS After Only A Couple Nodes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frame-rate

So when I run my game on iOS there is extremely low Frames Per Second. It is a game that generates 3 people and that is it but the FPS is an absolute killer.
I also attempted to run my game on an actual iPhone and iPad and the FPS was still bad.

I'm talking about something like 2 FPS for 5 Nodes here.

[Game Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEv2w.png)

After removing a player the FPS increases and after removing 2 it is properly running at about 60 FPS.

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks.

Recieved this in console:

```
2016-07-30 12:11:04.034 PokeMurder[850:443325] CUICatalog: Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom  
2016-07-30 12:11:04.066 PokeMurder[850:443325] CUICatalog: Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom  
2016-07-30 12:11:05.553 PokeMurder[850:443325] <SKMetalLayer: 0x14cd60440>: calling -display has no effect.
```

**EDIT:** *I have fixed the problem, the error was that there were physics bodies overlapping each other which was for some reason causing a lot of lag.*

Comment: What game engine are you using? I'm not experienced at game development at all, but it could be a memory problem.

Comment: @tktsubota It's coded in Swift using SpriteKit for iOS, my mac has 16GB RAM so it should be plenty of memory.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using?